# Rails create form for model with many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model, many-to-many

I have two models, `Recipe` and `Tag`, with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation. For this relation I have a simple join table, `RecipesTags`.

Recipe:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
```

Tag:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
```

Now upon creating a new recipe, the user gets to fill in which category the recipe belongs to in forms of checkboxes, like "Meat", "Fish", and so on. These categories are in fact just tags in the database.

**Problem: the recipes doesn't get any tags saved to it.**

Recipe `new` and `create` controller methods:

```
    def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
    @tags = Tag.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
  end



  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    if (params[:tags])
      @recipe.tags << params[:tags]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The view:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

# [ fields that get's saved for the recipe and works fine ]

<% @tags.each do |t| %>
      <%= f.label t.name  %>
      <%= f.check_box :tags, t.name  %>
      <br />
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit 'Submit recipe', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

At the moment, I get an error message saying: 
undefined method `merge' for "Meat":String

"Meat" is the tag name.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your form working fine? When you are getting this error?

Comment: I've posted an answer below, but for future reference it's usually helpful to provide a bit more of the error message, such as the exception that was raised (usually the first part of the bold heading on the page, i.e. `NoMethodError`), and where the exception was raised (in your case this probably looks something like `app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:21:in 'create'`), which tells you exactly which line in which file caused the exception. This is very helpful as it gives us a starting point to figure out which bit of the code is faulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is this line `@recipe.tags << params[:tags]`. 
The association method you're calling with `<<` takes an object (in this case expecting a tag object), but in this case it seems you might be passing it a string.

For more info this link may be helpful http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference, in particular where it refers to `collection<<(object, …)`.

---

In your controller you'll want to do something like `@recipe.tags << tag` where tag is a specific tag object.

So, try this:

*In your controller*

```
params[:tags].each do |k,v|
   @recipe.tags << Tag.find(k)
end
```

*In your view*

```
<% @tags.each do |t| %>
  <%= f.label t.name  %>
  <%= f.check_box "tags[#{t.id}]"  %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: How about checked save after you are redirected back to show after validation error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    params[:tags].each do |tag|
      @recipe.tags << Tag.find_by_name(tag)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In view:

```
<% @tags.each do |t| %>
  <%= label_tag t.name  %>
  <%= check_box_tag "tags[#{t.name}]", t.name  %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```