# Rails : assign multiple params via form_for check_box for HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm a rails noob working on my first own project.

I got two models linked using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship : Wine and Shop . To make it simple a wine can be sold in different shops and a specific shop can sell many different wines. Here are the models :

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :wines
end

class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
end
```

My goal is to make a form to create instances of Wine including the Shops where the wine can be purchased. Here is my wines_controller :

```
  def new
    @wine = wine.new
    @shops = Shop.all

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @wine }
    end
  end

 def create
    @wine = Wine.new(params[:wine])
    params[:shops].each do |id|
      @wine.shops << Shop.find(id)
    end 
end
```

Here is my _form view rendered in new view :

```
<%  @shops.each do |t|  %>
<%= f.label t.name  %>
<%= f.check_box :shops, t.id %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried many things and spent hours on this but can't found the solution. Among other things I had a look at those issues but I could not get it working :

- [Rails create form for model with many to many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188936/rails-create-form-for-model-with-many-to-many-relation)
- [update values of checkbox with HABTM relationship -- Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263333/update-values-of-checkbox-with-habtm-relationship-rails)
- [Creating multiple records in a HABTM relationship using a collection_select - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107343/creating-multiple-records-in-a-habtm-relationship-using-a-collection-select-ra)

Lastly I got an

```
undefined method `merge' for 3:Fixnum
```

Just let me know if you need any other details to deal with this issue or if there is already a question about this that I have missed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%  @shops.each do |t|  %>
  <%= f.label t.name  %>
  <%= check_box_tag "shops[]", t.id %>
<% end %>
```

and your controller code

```
def create
  @wine = Wine.new(params[:wine])
  @shops = Shop.find params[:shops]
  @wine.shops = @shops
  ..
```

Comment: You can also simplify you crreate method: ` @wine = Wine.new(params[:wine])
    @wine.shops << Shop.find(params[:shops])
    end`

Comment: I still get `undefined method `merge' for 3:Fixnum` with 3 being the id of one of the shop

Comment: @Santosh already tried that one ;) I get `undefined method `check_box_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x3c774f0`

Comment: @BroiSatse thanks for this, but it seems that it's not solving the problem with the view.

Comment: @Santosh - You will get 'unknown attribute 'shops' for Wine. You need move @shops assignment over @wine assignment and change it to `@shops = Shop.find params[:wine].delete(:shops)`

Comment: @BroiSatse your solution is working well, thanks a lot. I would really appreciate if you could explain the `params[:wine].delete(:shops)` part a little bit more.

Comment: @SBfrr - It simply removes `shops` key from `params[:wine]` hash and returns value under this key.