# form in a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

Im starting with rails.

Im trying to implement a has_many_belongs_to_many relationship between two models, project and users, I did with a simple join table as well. But I can´t do that work. Im getting crazy with this. I would appreciate if anybody can help.
I try this solution but its giving me a mistake

[Rails : assign multiple params via form_for check_box for HABTM relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574404/rails-assign-multiple-params-via-form-for-check-box-for-habtm-relationship/27175308#27175308)
Controler:

```
 def create
 @users = User.find params[:project].delete[:users]
 @project = Project.new(params[:project])
 @project.users = @users
```

.....

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:client_id, :pstate_id, :name, 
  :description,  :start_date, :deadline, :is_closed, :workload, :users_ids => [])
  end
```

My view is:

```
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :user_ids, "Users" %><br />
 <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, 
 {multiple: true}    %>
 </div>
```

And now I get this mistake:

```
ArgumentError in ProjectsController#create
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #37):

35
36
37
38
39
40




authorize! :create, @project
#@project = Project.new(project_params)
@users = User.find params[:project].delete[:users]
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
@project.users = @users
#@users = @user.projects

Rails.root: C:/Ruby200/onlineproyect
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:37:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"wU9MgWv40XMqoy0sDZXd5vtqpFGxXHPmLNm/BmrvVZY=",
 "project"=>{"client"=>"1",
 "pstate"=>"1",
 "name"=>"Projecto 1",
 "description"=>"el ultimo",
 "start_date(1i)"=>"2014",
 "start_date(2i)"=>"11",
 "start_date(3i)"=>"27",
 "deadline(1i)"=>"2014",
 "deadline(2i)"=>"11",
 "deadline(3i)"=>"27",
 "workload"=>"",
 "user_ids"=>["",
 "1",
 "2"]},
"commit"=>"Create Project"}
```

-I have tried many different things....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
@users = User.find params[:project].delete[:user_ids]
```